# Querying with bind parameters in codeigniter

Tags: php

I have this query string,

```
SELECT Name, LastN, Code FROM Acc WHERE Name = ? AND Code = md5(concat(LastN, ? )) 

$query = $this->db->query($sql, array($name,$key));
```

How do I concatenate the string LastN and the $key?
I am using CodeIgniter.

```
if($query -> num_rows() == 1)
{
  return "Yes";
}
else
{
  return "No";
}
```

This is the if-else condition.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? How is it not working? Do you get any error message? If not add `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your script and try again.

Comment: If the $query returns 1 row, it will return string "Yes", if not, it will return "No", I get the NO string.